# Parse XAML using XDocument class C#

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml

I am trying to get the workflow tag using XDocument class but it is given me below mentioned exception :

**The ':' character, hexadecimal value 0x3A, cannot be included in a name.**

I have also tried using namespace but no positive result achieved.

**XML:**

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
        <Activity x:Class="XrmWorkflow75328ae32924499d972dd68053611740" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/netfx/2009/xaml/activities" xmlns:mxswa="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Workflow.Activities;assembly=Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Workflow, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" xmlns:s="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" xmlns:this="clr-namespace:" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
            <mxswa:Workflow>
                <mxswa:ActivityReference AssemblyQualifiedName="Microsoft.Crm.Workflow.Activities.ConditionSequence, Microsoft.Crm.Workflow, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" DisplayName="ConditionStep1: name">
</mxswa:ActivityReference>
            </mxswa:Workflow>
        </Activity>
```

**CODE :**

```
 string strXml = File.ReadAllText(@"../../XMLFile1.xml");
            XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Parse(strXml);
              XNamespace xmlns = "clr-namespace:Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Workflow.Activities;assembly‌​=Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.W‌​orkflow, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35";
        var results = from node in xdoc.Descendants( xmlns + "Workflow")
                      select node;
```

results is always null.

Comment: There is no `Arguments` node in your sample xml

Comment: Your `mxswa:ActivityReference` node doesn't have an end tag.

Comment: please check again question has been edit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I am trying to get the workflow tag

As @Sergey Berezovskiy mentioned you need to use the `XNamespace`.

Here is the complete working example.

```
var xml = @"<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""utf-16""?>
    <Activity x:Class=""XrmWorkflow75328ae32924499d972dd68053611740"" xmlns=""http://schemas.microsoft.com/netfx/2009/xaml/activities"" xmlns:mxswa=""clr-namespace:Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Workflow.Activities;assembly=Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Workflow, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"" xmlns:s=""clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"" xmlns:this=""clr-namespace:"" xmlns:x=""http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"">
        <mxswa:Workflow>
            <mxswa:ActivityReference AssemblyQualifiedName=""Microsoft.Crm.Workflow.Activities.ConditionSequence, Microsoft.Crm.Workflow, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"" DisplayName=""ConditionStep1: name"" />
        </mxswa:Workflow>
    </Activity>";

XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Parse(xml);
XNamespace xnamespace = "clr-namespace:Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Workflow.Activities;assembly=Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Workflow, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35";
var nodes = xdoc.Descendants(xnamespace + "Workflow");
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is correct way of using namespace in element name:

```
xdoc.Descendants(xmlns + "ActivityReference.Arguments")
```

I.e. its `XNamespace` plus local name string.

Note: there is no `mxswa:ActivityReference.Arguments` node in your sample xml and your `mxswa:ActivityReference` do not have closing tag.

Comment: your code is not working. have you checked is it working ?

Comment: @ShujaatSiddiqui You need to use the full namespace or it wont work. `clr-namespace:Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Workflow.Activities;assembly=Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Workflow, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35`

Comment: @ShujaatSiddiqui it works, use correct value of `xmlns:mxswa`

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy yes it is working but i have to use full namespace